# Is there way to list only non-default installed packages

Tags: linux

Is there way to list only non-default installed packages?

Something similar to `rpm -qa` output, but only with user installed packages (non-default).

Edit: the Distro is Oracle Linux

Answer (score 2):

```bash
dnf list installed | grep -E -v "@fedora|@updates"
```

You've not specified your distro, so I assumed it's Fedora. If it's e.g. rhel or centos, replace @fedora above accordingly. If it's Suse or Mandriva, I've no idea. Haven't used them.

Comment: Sorry, my distro is Oracle Linux

Comment: Run `dnf list installed`, you'll see what your distro designation for dnf is.

Comment: @Potter What do you mean by "non-default". I have quite a few packages installed from "ol_baseos_latest" that I had to specifically ask for. Do you mean only all packages that are installed when you select something like multi-user desktop in the installation menu? If so, your only option is to look through | /var/log/dnf* and try to see what packages were installed manually. Grepping for  packages that did not come from ol_baseos_latest or appstream will only tell you packages that came from outside repositories. [cont]

Comment: @Potter Do you consider packages coming from oel_UEKR6, epel, or codeready to be "foreign" packages?